# Maximize norms & fraction

Tags: real-analysis

Let $A$ be pos. def., $M$ be rectangular.

$$\frac{\lVert A^{1/2} v \rVert}{ \lVert  M^T A v \rVert} $$

I want to calculate the maximum of the above fraction.

Comment: Isn't this just a generalized eigenvalue problem in the numerator and denominator matrices? I don't think you'll end up with a closed form solution, but something like scipy's linalg.eigen function could do the trick numerically.

Comment: The Lagrangian can be written as $L(v,\lambda)= v^T B v -\lambda (v^T C v -1)$ which seems trivial.

Answer (score 1):

This is a generalized eigenvalue problem defined by the matrices in your numerator and denominator.

The generalized eigenvalues are the Lagrange multipliers, and the solution is the maximum generalized eigenvalue. You can find an in-depth connection between the optimization formulation you posited and generalized eigenvalues in section 4.1 of this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1903.11240.pdf

Comment: Let $C = p^{T} A p$ and $D = p^{T} A M (M^{T} A M)^{-1} M^{T} A p$.  Then your problem is $\max_{\phi \in \mathbb{R}^{d}} \phi^{T} C \phi$ subject to $\phi^{T} D \phi = 1$. The solution is the maximum value $\lambda$ that satisfies the generalized eigenvalue equation $C \phi = \lambda B \phi$.